# The isomorphism between $F^B$ and $V$ of dimension $|B|$

Tags: linear-algebra

$F^B$  is  the  set  of  functions  from  the  set  $B$   to  the  set  $F$  with  *finite support* . Let $B$  has  cardinality  $\kappa $ . Then to  show  any vector  space $V$ of  dimension  $\kappa$  over $F$  is  isomorphic  to  $F^B$.

If the  number  $\kappa$  is  finite  or  countable  then  I  can  show  the  bijection . For *uncountable*  if  I  do  the  following , is  it  correct  $?$

Let $V_B$  be  the basis  of  $V$  and  $D_B=\{\delta_{b}(x)=\delta_{bx}\}$  be  the  basis  for $F^B$.

Let $\Psi$  be  the  correspondence   between $F^B$  and  $V$ 
Choose  any $\delta_{b_k}$  from  $F^B$  and  any $v_k$ and  write $$\
\Psi(\delta_{b_k})=v_k$$
Now for  the  sets $D_B\backslash \delta_{b_k}$ and $V_B\backslash v_k$. Similar  arbitrary  choices  make  $\Psi $  into  a  bijection .

Also  , after  bijection is proved , I have to show linearity  of  the  map . i.e. $$\Psi(\alpha\delta_{b_k}+\beta\delta_{b_j})=\alpha\Psi(\alpha\delta_{b_k})+\beta\Psi(\alpha\delta_{b_j})=\alpha v_k +\beta v_j$$
How  do  I  prove  that $?$

Comment: You really should make use of the assumption that $V_B$ and $D_B$ have the same cardinality. From a bijection between these bases it is easy to get a linear isomorphism between the vector spaces. An inductive approach is not necessary, as is the division into the cases finite, countable, uncountable cardinality.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch : I'm  trying , I  can't .

Answer (score 1):

Using your notation, by assumption there is a bijection $f : D_B \to V_B$. We are going to define a linear map $\Psi_f : F^B \to V$. Let $x \in F^B$, then we can express $x$ as a linear combination $x = \sum_{b \in B} x_b \delta_b $ (only finitely many $x_b$ non-zero). Now we set $$\Psi_f(x) = \sum_{b \in B} x_b f(\delta_b).$$ This is well-defined, because the linear combination expressing $x$ in the basis $D_B$ is unique.

This gives a well-defined map $\Psi_f : F^B \to V$. To check linearity, note that for $x,y \in F^B$ and $\alpha,\beta \in F$ writing $x = \sum_{b} x_b \delta_b$, $y = \sum_{b} y_b \delta$, then $\alpha x + \beta y = \sum_{b} (\alpha x_b + \beta y_b) \delta_b$, so that 
$$ \Psi_f(\alpha x + \beta b) = \sum_{b} (\alpha x_b + \beta y_b) f(\delta_b) = \alpha \sum_{b} x_b f(\delta_b) + \beta \sum_{b} y_b f(\delta_b) = \alpha\Psi_f(x) + \beta \Psi_f(y)$$ 
where in the first and third step we use the definition of $\Psi_f$ and in the second we just rewrite the sum.

Now using that $f$ is injective if $\Psi_f(x) = \Psi_f(y)$ then we conclude from $V_B$ being a basis (in particular linear, independent) that $x_b = y_b$ for all $b \in B$. Hence $\Psi_f$ is injective.

Also for $v \in V$ we express $v$ as a linear combination $v = \sum_{b \in B} v_b f(\delta_b)$ because $V_B$ is a basis of $V$ and $f$ is surjective. Now we see that $\Psi_f(\sum_{b} v_b \delta_b) = v$ so $\Psi_f$ is surjective.

Putting all things together, we get that $\Psi_f$ is a linear isomorphism between $F^B$ and $V$.

Note that this shows in fact the following.
If $V$ and $W$ are two vector spaces over $F$ with basis $B_V$ and $B_W$, respectively, then any map $f : B_V \to B_W$ extends to a linear map $\Psi_f : V \to W$ in a unique way. Moreover, $f$ is injective (surjective) if and only if $\Psi_f$ is injective (surjective).

Comment: There is only 1 point I don't get.For proving injectivity:Let $\Psi_f(x)=\Psi_f(y)$.We have to prove that $x=y$ but we don't know it yet so let's assume that $x=x_{b_1}\delta(b_1)+...x_{b_n}\delta(b_n)$ and $y=y_{b_1}\delta(b_1)+...y_{b_m}\delta(b_m)$.. Then $\Psi_f(x)=\Psi_f(y)$  implies $\sum_{i=1}^n x_{b_i}\delta(b_i)=\sum_{i=1}^m y_{b_i}\delta(b_i)$ . Now wlg assuming $n\ge m$, substracting RHS from LHS the  equation we get is a linear combination of $\delta(b_i)$'s and by *linear independence* of them we get  $n=m$ and $x_b=y_b$ $\forall b$ . But I did not need the injectivity of $f$ .

Comment: Another question for  the bijection ,. Is  my  way of proving the bijection for   *uncountable* case  correct $?$

Comment: To answer your first question, note that $\Psi_f(x) = \Psi_f(y)$ does *not* imply $\sum_{b} x_b \delta_b = \sum_{b} y_b \delta_b$ but only $\sum_{b} x_b f(\delta_b) = \sum_{b} y_b f(\delta_b)$. To conclude that $x_b = y_b$ for all $b$ we have to use that the $f(\delta_b)$ are all distinct for different $b$ and linear independent. Otherwise, if we had $f(\delta_b) = f(\delta_{b'})$ for $b \neq b'$, then $x = \delta_b$, $y = \delta_{b'}$ are two different elements of $F^B$ both mapping to the element in $V$ via $\Psi_f$ and $\Psi_f$ would not be injective.

Comment: It is not clear to me between which sets you want to get a bijection. Between $D_B$ and $V_B$ ? There you already know (by assumption) that there is a bijection and you do not have to construct one. Or between $F^B$ and $V$? Anyway, the idea to pick elements from one set and map them in some arbitrary way to elements in another set and repeating this with those elements removed fails in general to grant you a bijection, simply because in the infinite case there are proper subsets with the same cardinality as the whole set and you might end up with a map which is not bijective.

Comment: I  got  the  *injection* part  right  this  time. thanks .    For  the  other  part , bijection is not assumed between the  sets  $V_B$   and  $D_B$ .

Comment: Your assumption is that $V$ has dimension $\kappa$ which is equivalent with $V_B$ having cardinality $\kappa$ which is also the cardinality of $D_B$, so there exists a bijection between $V_B$ and $D_B$ by assumption.